# Notepad++: regex as replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm busy inserting my url aliases into a database. And need to make insert queries from the list of values i have.

A few items from my list:

```
(NULL, 'tag=23525','2807016'),
(NULL, 'tag=23525','10165'),
(NULL, 'tag=23525','12165'),
```

I'd love to have a regex expression which can find tag=23525 and can replace it with the number behind it.
So the list will end up looking like this:

```
(NULL, 'tag=2807016','2807016'),
(NULL, 'tag=10165','10165'),
(NULL, 'tag=12165','12165'),
```

I've managed to find the text tag=23525 (wow so hard). But i'm stuck with the finding (the replace) of the number behind.

I can find the last number easily with this regex but can't replace with this regex:

`^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\b(\w+)\b`

How am i able to find and replace `tag=23525` with the match found from the regex?

Comment: Voted your question up, because after working for a years with notepad++. I never even notice there is ability to replace with regex. 
Anyway I figure it out and added solution below, hope it helpes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=tag=)\d+('\s*,\s*')(\d+)
```

You can use this.Replace by `$2$1$2` or `\2\1\2`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/4

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what i wanted :)!

Answer (score 0):

Was a little tricky but here is how you can do it:

```
\d+(',')(\d+)
```

and replace with

```
$2$1$2
```

One picture == thousand words

[image]

Comment: My bad, it's (?!) instead of (?:) - correcting now. Thanks @vks

Comment: Why not correct? from my tests - it replaces exactly the needed values. See in image above

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/5 see here..it will replace any number...it does not look for `tag`

Comment: Yes you right, but knowing the format we can make it our advantage and do it even shorter like this: `\d+(',')(\d+)`

Comment: That will replace all...OP clearly says `I'd love to have a regex expression which can find tag=23525 and can replace it with the number `

Comment: @vks you right, but he also gave the string format on which me (and also you) based the needed regex. So yes if the format would change as for example  'tag= removed ,or something else like instead of single quotation mark (') will be double quotation (") or instead of comma separator will be semicolon (or any other change) -> that will immediately make regex ineffective.